# nginx + php5-fpm + cifs share + CakePHP timeout

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cifs, cakephp

I recently moved my cakephp 3 dev environment onto a network share.

The server in question has only had a path change for the nginx webroot (`root /var/www/webroot`, to `root /mnt/dev/webroot`).

I am mounting the CIFS share via `/etc/fstab` as follows:

`//nfs/WebDev /mnt/dev  cifs username=webdev,password=hunter2,gid=www-data,uid=www-data,rw,noserverino 0 0`

For some reason cakephp index page times out when I access the index page (nginx 504: Gateway Timeout).
If I create a test script of

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

The page loads instantly with the correct output - this shows there should be no issue between nginx and php-fpm.

When I run `time /mnt/dev/webroot/index.php` from the shell, I get the correct HTML output and the command executes in less than 1 second. This shows that php-cli can read from the NFS share and executes properly.

I am at a total loss as to what has caused the dev server to completely break and would gladly appreciate any help into understanding why it is being an absolute utter pain!

[Config Files](https://hcbj.io/nginx_config.html) (sorry I had to link all the config files on a single page).

Edit:

- If I run `php -S localhost:8080` on Windows on the webroot directory, everything works fine
- If I run `php -S dev.local:8080` on the Dev Server on the webroot directory, everything runs and I can access it from my Windows machine

Comment: May be problem not with your mounted cifs share. Error 504 return when your upstream aswers more then default timeout(60 seconds). Could you enable php-fpm logs and check what you receive. Also please share output for `ls -la /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

Comment: [/var/log/php5-fpm.log](https://pastebin.com/m15K0LED)  
`ls` output: `srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jun  7 19:22 /run/php5-fpm.sock`  
  
I've just copied the entirety of the CIFS share to the local drive and see if that makes a difference, will update in a bit...

Answer (score 0):

A clean install of Debian + nginx + php5-fpm solved my issue and the fresh dev server install works.

As to the root cause, I'm unsure, but will diff the config files and work out what the hell I was doing that caused the fuckery